# How to join first letter of a list with all the letters of another and print it

Tags: python, list

I have two python lists, namely,
`num = ['0', '1']`
and
`salpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`
and\

```
I want the result to be,\
```

0a
0b
0c
0d
0e
0@
0#
1a
1b
1c
1d
1e
1@
1#\

```
How can I do that..??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
num = ['0', '1']
salpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in num:
  for j in salpha:
    print(i+j)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is:

```
num = ['0', '1']
salpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in num:
    for j in salpha:
        print(i+j)
```